# Xamarin Forms Load image from folder inside project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am trying to save an Image to a folder in my project (not the Resources folder!) and load theimage from that folder into an Image holder as source. I want the image to be saved in a folder called: **TempImages** and my app name is MyApp. Here is the code I have now:

**Saving**:

```
using (var image = args.Surface.Snapshot())
using (var data = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 80))
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine("MyApp.TempImages", "CreatedImage.png")))
{
    data.SaveTo(stream);
}
```

**Opening**:

```
string resourceID = string.Format("MyApp.TempImages.CreatedImage.png");
Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID);
imgCanvas.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(resourceID);
```

But I think that `File.OpenWrite` a local file on my pc means, but I am not sure. And therefore I am not sure if I am opening the file correctly. Now I get the error that the save path doesn't exist.

How can I fix this?

Comment: the app bundle is read-only.  Read the docs on file handling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Comment: Okay so, to open the image I need to do this: `imgCanvas.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(path, typeof(EmbeddedImages).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);` But that gives me an error on `EmbeddedImages`, because that doesn't exist in the current context?

Comment: `EmbeddedImages` - this should be the name of any class in your project.  But you will still not be able to write to it.

Comment: I have no class named EmbeddedImages? And how can I save an image as an EmbeddedResource?

Comment: replace "EmbeddedImages" with the **name of.a class in your project**.  And you can't save an image as an EmbeddedResource at run time.  You just save it as a regular file.

Comment: But how can I save the image of the surface, so I can load it?

Comment: the 2nd section of the doc I just linked to is **Saving and Loading Files**

Comment: Okay, so now I have: `var stream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CreatedImage.png"))`, but how can I enter another folder? Do I need to put that like this: `MyFolder.CreatedImage.png`?

Comment: System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory();

Comment: I mean in the `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CreatedImage.png")`

Comment: use the path returned by `Environment.GetFolderPath` and create whatever subfolder structure you want underneath it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204635/discussion-between-vreesie-and-jason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to create any folder structure you want within one of the app writeable paths

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

var folder = Path.Combine(path,"MySpecialFolder");

Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

var file = Path.Combine(folder,"MyImage.png");

File.WriteAllBytes(file,data);

var image = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
```

Comment: Thanks, I combined the code I created by your instructions with your awnser!!!